# How to add CSS to my html in Google Script mail?

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

```
function sendWeeklyReportEmails() {
  var subject;
  var indicesHTML;
  var advancedArgs;

  subject = "Your Weekly Report on Financial Markets";
  indicesHTML = getIndicesReport("Weekly");
  advancedArgs = {htmlBody: indicesHTML};
  MailApp.sendEmail("abc@gmail.com", subject, "", advancedArgs);
}
```

I want to add CSS to my "htmlBody" content. How should I do id?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```js
var mailBody = '<table style="width:100%"><tr><td>name 1</td><td>address 1</td><td>age 1</td></tr><tr><td>name 2</td><td>address 2</td><td>age 2</td></tr></table>'
MailApp.sendEmail('youremail@yourdomain.xyz',' Email title',mailBody,{'htmlBody':mailBody});
```

Comment: How can I add css to this ?

Comment: you could use inline css like: <p style="color:red;font-size:18px">This is a paragraph!</p>